# Run a python script from a .bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a few compiled python scripts packaged in a zip file (app.zip) and activated by a .bat file. The .bat file runs the program in the native cmd shell when double-clicked. Is it possible to somehow configure the .bat file to run the script in MS Windows Terminal [MS Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)  instead of the native cmd shell?

Here's how the .bat file currently runs the program in the native cmd:

```
@echo off
start "My_App" cmd /k python "app.zip" %*
```

I've tried changing `cmd` to `terminal` but it didn't work. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from another source. Posting here to help others

```
@echo off
wt -d . python "app.zip" %*
```